# nginx/flask application throws 500 error, after adding form to html file

Tags: nginx, flask, config

im trying to resolve a problem Im having with nginx. Nginx is throwing a `500 error` upon refresh.

Im simply trying to display a `form` on an `html` page via `flask`

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextField, StringField, SubmitField, validators

class EmailForm(FlaskForm):
  email = TextField("Email")
  submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

**routes.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from forms import EmailForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'xx'

# add mail server config
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'xxx'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'xx'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'xx'

mail = Mail(app)
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def email():
    form = EmailForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            return 'Please fill in all fields <p><a href="/contact">Try Again!!!</a></p>'
        else:
            msg = Message("Message from your visitor",
                          sender='xxx',
                          recipients=['xxx'])
            msg.body = """
            From: %s <%s>,
            %s
            """ % (form.email.data)
            mail.send(msg)
            return "Successfully  sent message!"
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**index.html**

```
        <form action="{{ url_for('email') }}" method="post">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

            {{ form.email }}
            {{ form.submit }}
        </form>
```

What am I doing wrong? My site just throws a `500 internal server` error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a couple things wrong here. Firstly, you aren't using `FlaskForm`, you're using the standard `Form`, which does not come with `csrf_token` that you would use `hidden_tag()` for. That's probably the source of the error. So in **forms.py**:

Replace `from flask_wtf import Form` with `from flask_wtf import FlaskForm` and `class EmailForm(Form):` with `class EmailForm(FlaskForm):`

Next, `validators.Email('your@email.com')` doesn't make any sense. The only argument that the `Email()` validator accepts is an error message for the end user. You should either remove it, or replace it with something like `validators.Email('That is not an email!')`

**EDIT**

As davidism pointed out, the form import is fine, just depricated. If you had done `from wtforms import Form`, *that* would be wrong. The real problem seems to be here:

```
msg = Message("Message from your visitor" + form.name.data,
                      sender='xxx',
                      recipients=['xxx'])
msg.body = """
From: %s <%s>,
%s
""" % (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data)
mail.send(msg)
```

You keep referencing `form.name.data` and `form.message.data`, which don't exist. Your `EmailForm` has no `name` or `message` field defined in it. You should either remove them if you didn't want a name or message field, or add them to your `EmailForm` class if you forgot it.

Comment: I added this to `routes.py` and `app.py` but it isnt showing anything. where can i see the results

Comment: This is showing an error in /var/log/nginx/error.log of: 2016/12/12 16:37:24 [error] 983#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: site.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: "site.com"

Comment: @Jshee My first question would be, did you add a name and message field to your form class? Something like these: `name =  StringField('Name', [validators.DataRequired()])` and `message =  StringField('Message', [validators.DataRequired()])`. Secondly, did you setup the correct information to connect to the mail server?

Comment: Yes on both. Please see updated. I removed any `name` or `message` and just need `email`

Comment: @Jshee You still need to remove the two extra bits of string formatting from `From: %s <%s>,%s`. It should look like `From: %s`.

Comment: I removed the extra %s, but still get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130541/discussion-between-taehan-stott-and-jshee).